# Unchecked Cast Warning when calling 'Class.forName'

Tags: java, casting, compiler-warnings

My code is as follows

```
package com.foo;

public class TestComposition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class<Foo> fooClass = 
                    (Class<Foo>) Class.forName("Foo");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The assignment within the 'try' block results in a warning stating

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#1-of ?> to 
     Class<Foo>
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, to start with let's be clear where the problem is - it's in the cast itself. Here's a shorter example:

```
public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Object x = (Class<Test>) Class.forName("Test");
    }
}
```

This still has the same problem. The issue is that the cast isn't actually going to test anything - because the cast will be effectively converted to the raw `Class` type. For `Class<T>` it's slightly more surprising because in reality the object *does* know the class involved, but consider a similar situation:

```
List<?> list = ... get list from somewhere;
List<String> stringList = (List<String>) list;
```

That cast isn't going to check that it's *really* a `List<String>`, because that information is lost due to *type erasure*.

Now in your case, there's actually a rather simpler solution - if you know the class name at compile-time anyway, just use:

```
Class<Foo> fooClass = Foo.class;
```

If you can provide a more realistic example where that's *not* the case, we can help you determine the most appropriate alternative.

Comment: I think the real problem is; Why use Class.forName() if you know the type?

Comment: Is this because this is a run-time operation? So, the quintessence is that at compile time the '(Class<Test>)' is superfluous because the 'types' are removed by the compiler after compilation - the compiler can't know if the loaded class will be a 'Test'?

Comment: @Joeblackdev: It's because at *execution time* objects don't have that generic type information in general. If you call `getClass()` on an `ArrayList<String>` it'll be the same value as if you call it on an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - I think I see what you mean. Why not just create an instance of 'Foo' instead...

Comment: @Peter: Well that's *part* of the problem (as I mention in my post) but this may well have come from a more complicated example which makes more sense. It's worth understanding the principles behind the warning, IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet that's what I was thinking. The compiler will remove all 'type' information in the end. Ok, i'll avoid using Class.forName. I don't think it really makes sense in this instance.

Comment: @Jon, no the above example is perfect. For some reason unbeknown to me, I forget that you can call `MyClass.class`

Comment: There may be several implementations of Foo, and one would want to select which at run time.

Answer (score 43):

Firstly, if you know the exact class then you don't need `Class.forName`. `Foo.class` will do. (Prior to J2SE 5.0, `Foo.class` actually compiled to doing `Class.forName("Foo")` and then caching it in a static.)

What you probably want is something like:

```
Class<? extends Foo> fooClass =
    (Class<? extends Foo>) Class.forName("MyFoo");
```

(When I say want, casts and particularly reflection are evil.)

As it happens, you there is an appropriate method to do the cast "safely" (assuming `Foo` is not itself generic). Safely as in not providing a reference to an incompatible object, not as in there are no bug or no unexpected exception.

```
Class<? extends Foo> fooClass =
    Class.forName("MyFoo").asSubclass(Foo.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

The runtime system has no knowledge about generics and therfore it can only check that something is of type `Class`, not if it is of type `Class<Test>`. That is what the warning is about.

A method has specifically been added to the `Class` class to avoid this warning. You can use this instead of casting yourself: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass(java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 1):

If you knew the exact class, you wouldn't need to use Class.forName

```
Class<Foo> fooClass = Foo.class;
```

It only makes sense to do this when you don't know the type.